# Should we make different reducers for a single object received as api response in order to avoid complexity. Or have one reducer for it

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an api response like

booking ->
booking details,
guests list,
notes,
guests notes,
documents,
booking activity,
payments,
emails etc

Each of the above items then have actions such add/edit/delete, so having them in one reducer will make that reducer quite big and difficult to manage.
Should I have one reducer per item? And if I do that then how pass data to specific reducers. e.g. After successfully fetching booking details I then pass the different items to different reducers respectively? Is this a good and manageable approach?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application structure. you should create one reducer per parent component, but if you feel, it is getting bigger and face difficulty to manage, then you should find out your child components used and create reducers individually for them.

Best way to manage your Application easily and reusable is to follow [Atomic Design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/). But again I am saying it will depend on Architecture of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider each item type (ie. `booking`, `guest`, `document`, etc.) as an entity.  Read up on [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) in the redux docs.  You might consider using the [`normalizr`](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) package and/or redux-toolkit's [`createEntityAdapter`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) to do some of the work.

Each entity can be treated the same, you just need to include enough information in your action to identify the correct object in your state (ie. `type` and `id`).

You can deal with the different entities in an abstract way, but you can also create specific selectors.

```
const getEntity = (state, type, id) => state[type][id];

const getBooking = (state, id) => state.booking[id];
```

```
{
  type: 'UPDATE_ENTITY',
  payload: {
    type: 'booking',
    id: 5,
    changes: { /*...*/ }
  }
}
```

When you get an API response with many entities in it, you would normalize it first and then store all of the entities with one action.